# angular parallax - jquery to angular

Tags: angularjs

i have this code working in jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        $('.parallax-background').css('top', '' + ($(window).scrollTop() / 5) + 'px');
    });
</script>
```

and I'm trying to translate it into angular and this is what i believe it should be but its not working?

```
angular.module('twtscrollApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
        $window.on('scroll', function () {
            angular.element('.parallax-background').css('top', '' + ($window.scrollTop() / 5) + 'px');
        });
    });
```

im not getting any joshing errors but its not working, can do a jfiddle if need be, but any help appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason what you have does not work is because angular.element does not work via jQuery selectors, it only works via tag names. [**documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

In order to get what you have to work you would have to change

```
angular.element('.parallax-background')
```

to:

```
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('.parallax-background')[0])
```

### Suggested/Recommended Solution:

That being said, you should really consider doing this via a directive rather than in the controller as it is the appropriate place to put DOM manipulation.

Comment: I agree with the second part of this answer: Use a directive for this. The controller actually is the wrong place for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directives link function, which returns you the element itself so no need for DOM selectors.

```js
angular.module('myApp').directive('abc', function($timeout, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
           $window.on('scroll', function () {
              elem.css(.......);
           });
        }
    };
}
```

make sure you remove the listener when directive scope is destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Here is the better approach. Resposive background Parallax
Its allways better to use directive to inject jQuery. copy below code in separate file in your project then use this div tag in your Html

```
<div appParallax imgSrc="path-to-your-image" imgHeight="70vh"bgSize="cover"></div>
```

---

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, HostListener}from '@angular/core'; 

declare const $: any;
@Directive({
selector: '[appParallax]'
})
export class MyParallaxDirective implements OnInit {
@Input() imgSrc: string;
@Input() imgHeight: String = '70vh';
@Input() bgPosition: String = '50% 0';
@Input() bgSize: String = 'cover';
screenHeight: any;
screenWidth: any;
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private hostElement: ElementRef) 
{ }

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
ngOnInit() {
    this.innit();
    this.getScreenSize();
}
getScreenSize(event?) {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth - 100;
    const elem = this.hostElement.nativeElement;
    if (this.screenWidth <= 1024) {
        const $el = $(elem);
        const x = Math.round((window.innerWidth / 16) * 9);
        $el.css({ 'height': x + 'px' });
    }
}
innit() {
    const elem = this.hostElement.nativeElement;
    this.renderer.setStyle(elem, 'height', this.imgHeight);
    this.renderer.setStyle(elem, 'background-image', 'url' + '(' +this.imgSrc + ')'); 

    this.renderer.setStyle(elem, 'background-position', this.bgPosition);
    this.renderer.setStyle(elem, 'background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
    this.renderer.setStyle(elem, '-webkit-background-size', this.bgSize);
    this.renderer.setStyle(elem, 'background-size', this.bgSize);
    this.renderer.setStyle(elem, '-moz-transform', 'translate3d(0, 0,0)'); 

    this.renderer.setStyle(elem, '-webkit-transform', 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'); 

    this.renderer.setStyle(elem, 'transform', 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)');
    $(function () {
        const $el = $(elem);
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            const scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
            $el.css({
                'background-position': '50% ' + (-.4 * scroll) + 'px',
            });
        });
    });
  }
}
```

---

you can also download the file from here
[Responsive Angular Parallax](https://github.com/JubinSaniei/angular-Parallax)

Comment: This user is using AngularJS not Angular2+